# Pandas concatenation results in NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

What seems to be a simple function returns NaNs instead of the actual numbers. What am I missing here?

```
#Concatenate the dataframes:
dfcal = dfcal.astype(float)
dfmag = dfmag.astype(float)
print('dfcal\n-----',dfcal)
print('dfmag\n-----',dfmag)
df = pd.concat([dfcal,dfmag])
print('concatresult\n-----',df)
```

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need `axis=1` for append new columns, selected column `caliper` for avoid duplicated `depth` columns:

```
df = pd.concat([dfcal['caliper'],dfmag], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([dfcal.drop('depth', axis=1),dfmag], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check parameters (join, axis) or use merge

join{‘inner’, ‘outer’}, default ‘outer’

```
df = pd.concat([dfcal,dfmag], join='inner')
```